# Trying to build pkg-config

Tags: c++

I'm trying to build pkg-config in Windows so that I can make GIMP plugins. To build pkg-config, I apparently need to build autoconfig and automake. To build them, I need M4. To build that, I seem to need to build autoconfig and automake. What do I need to do?

I'm using MinGW-W64 and MSys2.

Comment: When asking a question, people will be better able to provide help if you provide code that they can easily understand and use to reproduce the problem. This is referred to by community members as creating a minimal, reproducible example (reprex), a minimal, complete and verifiable example ([mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)), or a minimal, workable example (mwe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using MSYS2 it is available to you already.
Just use `pacman` which comes with MSYS2 from the MSYS2 shell.
To update `pacman`'s package list run:

```
pacman -Syu --noconfirm
```

To get `pkg-config` run:

```
pacman -S --noconfirm git pkg-config
```

If you still want to have those configure tools run:

```
pacman -S --noconfirm git autoconf libtool automake
```